# Getting Ã¨Ã©@Ã Ã Ã Ã¹Ã character sending email via phpmailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

I'm getting Ã¨Ã©@Ã Ã Ã Ã¹Ã characters in mail when I'm sending mail via phpmailer if I'm using simple php mail function instead of phpmailer its working fine.

code:

```
<?php
require 'phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
$templatepath =  $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/customer/Templates/';
$body = file_get_contents($templatepath.$template_name);
$other['--TEMPLATE_URL--'] = $templatepath;
foreach($other as $k => $v) {
    $body = str_replace($k,$v,$body);
}
$body = wordwrap(trim($body), 70, "\r\n"); 
$body = convert_smart_quotes($body);
$mail = new PHPMailer;                
$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
$mail->Debugoutput = 'html';
$mail->Host = $email_hostname;                
$mail->Username = $email_username;
$mail->Password = $email_password;
$mail->setFrom($from_email, $company_name);
$mail->addReplyTo($from_email, $company_name);
$mail->addAddress($to, '');
$mail->Subject = $subject;
$mail->msgHTML($body);
if (!$mail->send()) {
    return 1;
} else {
    return 0;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have to add this line :

```
    $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
```

Answer (score 0):

May be this happen because of charset has not been set.

use it `$mail->CharSet = 'utf-8'` after `$mail = new PHPMailer();`